# Страницы сайта почему-то сдвинулись

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

http://websterjoy.tk/ - Если посмотреть на главную и потом перейти к примеру на "Обо мне", то увидите как страница немного сьезжает. Как это исправить? 
Но, я попробовал убрать в CSS float:left у элемента .about-me img и все стало нормально! почему float такое делает и как исправить??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сьезжает, потому что скрол появляется. вам нужно выставлять ширину главного блока на всю ширину окна браузера (без учета ширины скролбара). тогда все будет ровненько стоять вне зависимости от количества контента. посмотрите как это реализовано на http://vk.com и все станет ясно

Comment: не совсем понял Вас. Но я таки нашел проблему. На этой странице http://websterjoy.tk/services.html есть блок services и к нему прописано padding: 22px 22px 45px;. Так если убрать нижний (45px) то сдвиг убирается....можно узнать, чем тут паддинг так решил напортить мне? а он мне обязательно нужен

Comment: @websterjoy, здесь не в паддинге дело. дело в скролле, который появляется справа при большом количестве контента http://s018.radikal.ru/i516/1309/c8/d63859c3c1c7.jpg

Вам нужно создать основной блок, который будет на всю ширину окна браузера, но не учитывая скролбар (смотрите как это реализовано в ВК). Например, ширина окна 1920px, а ширина блока будет 1920 минус ширина скролбара, то есть 1920 - 18 = 1902px (это в Опере, в остальных браузерах не проверял). Тогда ничего никуда не будет сьезжать.

Comment: Все, до меня дошло) Только я таки не нашел вк как это реализовано.. решил сделать простым методом - overflow-y: scroll;

Answer (score 0):

Обычно разного рода `margin: 20px;` и растягивают сайт по ширине.

Уже все исправили?

Comment: нет, сейчас отличаются пункты "Портфолио" и "Услуги", они по разному все равно отображаются. Маргин не помогает, помогает только если убрать картинку

Comment: Так я и говорю, маргины и паддинги увеличивают даже фиксированную ширину контейнера ровно на ту ширину, на которую они расширяют свой контейнер. 
Ширина вашего сайта, как задано в .page: 920px; А у .about-me установлен padding: 22px 22px 60px; Соответсвенно, припишите у .about-me ширину width: 876px, и получится, что 876+22+22=920px.

Comment: да это я то знаю, но вы не поняли видимо... сайт не расширяется, а двигается почему-то...